# Post request in Spring Boot Controller throws "java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'columnname' cannot be null"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am starting to learn Spring Boot and I am currently trying to write my first API. The controller endpoint for creating new courses works just fine (by sending a JSON object via Postman). However, my endpoint for creating new applicants returns

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-14T15:21:47.189+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/demo/addapplicant"
}
```

in Postman and

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'gender'
> cannot be null

in the terminal window.
When I change my MySQL database to allow Nulls for gender it just gives the same Exception for a different attribute. I assume the JSON is not correctly translated into a Java Object. But since it works for the courses I am not sure what is causing the issue.

The Applicant class:

```
package com.example.demoSql;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Applicant {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  private String firstname;

  private String lastname;
  
  private String gender; //only m, w, d allowed
  
  private Date birthdate;
  
  private String city;
  
  private Integer zip_code;
  
  private String street;
  
  private String housenumber;
  
  private Float highschool_grade;
  
  private String highschool_certificate;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
  }

  public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }
  
  public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
  }

  public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }
  
  public String gender() {
    return gender;
  }

  public void gender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }
  
  public Date getBirthdate() {
    return birthdate;
  }

  public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
  }

  public String city() {
    return city;
  }

  public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
  }
  
  public Integer getZipCode() {
    return zip_code;
  }

  public void setZipCode(Integer zip_code) {
    this.zip_code = zip_code;
  }
  
  public String getStreet() {
    return street;
  }

  public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
  }
  
  public String getHousenumber() {
    return housenumber;
  }

  public void setHousenumber(String housenumber) {
    this.housenumber = housenumber;
  }
  
  public Float getHighschoolGrade() {
    return highschool_grade;
  }

  public void setHighschoolGrade(Float highschool_grade) {
    this.highschool_grade = highschool_grade;
  }
  
  public String getHighschoolCertificate() {
    return highschool_certificate;
  }

  public void setHighschoolCertificate(String highschool_certificate) {
    this.highschool_certificate = highschool_certificate;
  }
}
```

The Controller:

```
package com.example.demoSql;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller 
@RequestMapping(path="/demo")
public class MainController {
  @Autowired
  private CourseRepository courseRepository;
  @Autowired
  private ApplicantRepository applicantRepository;

  @PostMapping(path="/addcourse")
  public @ResponseBody String addNewCourse (@RequestBody Course course) {
    courseRepository.save(course);
    return "Saved";
  }

  @GetMapping(path="/allcourses")
  public @ResponseBody Iterable<Course> getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the courses
    return courseRepository.findAll();
  }
  
  @PostMapping(path="/addapplicant")
  public @ResponseBody String addNewApplicant (@RequestBody Applicant applicant) {
    applicantRepository.save(applicant);
    return "Saved";
  }
}
```

The JSON object:

```
{
    "firstname": "Erik",
    "lastname": "Bosse",
    "gender": "m",
    "city": "Stuttgart",
    "zip_code": 753924,
    "street": "Hauptstraße",
    "housenumber": "24",
    "highschool_grade": 1.5,
    "highschool_certificate": "C://dshfjhsdnsdklgdsl"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Mapping from json to java Obejct (Applicant) gender was set to null because you don't have the gender getter/setter in "Applicant" :

you need to use :

```
      public String getGender() {
        return gender;
      }
    
      public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
      }
```

insetad of :

```
      public String gender() {
        return gender;
      }

      public void gender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add your gender  Setter/Getter in your POJO. that will resolve your issue.
2. Also I can see you are not sure about your request body . In that case add "@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)" annotation on class level (POJO), So that unknown field can be ignored.
3. also define MediaType ( consumes/produces) in your code ( I mean to say what kind of request you are expecting from user).